# Create my own convolutional network without using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I've just started with AI and implementing my own CONV networks.

I have this conv network:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 150x150 with 3 bytes color
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2), 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
    # 512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'), 
    # Only 1 output neuron. It will contain a value from 0-1 where 0 for 1 class ('cats') and 1 for the other ('dogs')
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  
])
```

Is there any way to implement the Conv2D layers without using keras?

I want to try to understand how they work implementing them by myself.

Comment: Yes, you can. Andrew Ng in the course for Deep Learning Introduction teaches to implement Neural Networks from scratch. Likewise, CNNs were there way before tensorflow. So, you must be able to find a good source to implement CNN without APIs

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I have found this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-from-scratch-f1e3bfc3e2de

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I don't want to implement everything, only the Conv2D layer. By the way, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @VansFannel, you want to implement the 2D convolution operation by yourself? Is that what you want?

Comment: @thushv89 I want to implement the whole model. I know how to implement Maxpooling layers, but I don't know how to implement Conv2D layers. But in the previous article I got an idea about how to do it.

Comment: Did you try checking the source code of 2DConv layer?